# Maximum stack size over reached

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
   var myArray = [];
     $('#students_targeted option:selected,
#cc_students_targeted option:selected').each(function(){
       myArray.push(data);
     });
```

Comment: Hmmm. Maybe maximum stack size overreached?

Comment: How many `select` nodes are there ? What is `data` and where is it defined ?

Comment: 2 select nodes are there and the data is email

Comment: And what does the `data` contains and why you append to your array the same data several times?

Comment: Say what you want to append to `myArray`?

Comment: To myArray I am appending the list of emails selected into the select boxes, there are two select boxes one is for To:(to whom the data needs to sent) and other is CC (to whom the Carbon Copy of the mail is being sent)

Comment: To your array you are _not_ appending the list of emails, you're repeatedly appending the same 'data' which isn't connected to the selected options. I.e., all array elements will be the same. Please show a but more of your code and/or create a demonstration at http://jsfiddle.net.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This means that you have reached maximum stack size (in other words you have reached maximum limit of elements in array).

**UPD:** You probably need to use this code:

```
   var myArray = [];
     $('#students_targeted option:selected,
#cc_students_targeted option:selected').each(function(){
       myArray.push($(this).val());
     });
```

Comment: which seems highly unlikely, iterating over *selected* list elements.

Comment: Elements of which array @Danii

Comment: It seems to be `data` array. Looks like you push the same data to your array several time.

Comment: Thanks Danii works now it isn't stucking.Can you just indicate why myn aproach was incorrect.

Comment: That's because you tried to add `data` varaible to your array which was defined outside your `.each` loop so the same data was appended to your array again and again. To get the value of some input or option you need to use `.val()` method of your element. In this case `.val()` method of curent element (`this`) of `.each` loop